# jquery fadeIn/Out el then fadeIn/Out new el

Tags: jquery, click, fadein, fadeout

Sorry for title feel free to edit it,

Anyway this is the code I have so far

```
$('#foo').click(function() {

  $('#foo2').html('<h4>Please wait...</h4>').fadeOut('fast');

  var sful = $('#foo3').fadeIn('fast').html('<h4>Success!</h4>').fadeOut('slow');
  setTimeout(sful, 4000);

});
```

I'm trying to get **#foo2** to fadeIn on click, then for it to fadeOut and **#foo3** (var sful) to then fadeIn/Out after.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#foo2').html('<h4>Please wait...</h4>').fadeOut('fast', function() {
  var sful = $('#foo3').fadeIn('fast').html('<h4>Success!</h4>').fadeOut('slow');
  setTimeout(sful, 4000);
});
```

The **callback** (`function() { ..` will run after the animation has finished. See http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ (specifically the `[,callback]` section).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo2')
          .html('<h4>Please wait...</h4>')
          .fadeOut('fast', function() {  // callback start after fadeOut()
                             setTimeout(function() {
                                 $('#foo3')
                                       .fadeIn('fast')
                                       .html('<h4>Success!</h4>')
                                        .fadeOut('slow');
                              }, 4000);
                           });
```

Comment: You only need one duration argument, that might fail. Your code will fall under `.fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )` instead of  `.fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )`.